# PostgreSQL built-in indexes vs. manually created: Performance aspect

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to design an optimal index configuration for our application PostgreSQL DB and found that creating index manually for PK column seriously increases estimated performance. Initial idea came from [here, the first comment](http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2007/02/02/postgresql-unique-constraints-and-indexes).

Could someone explain:

1. Why PG uses manually created index instead of existing built-in one?
2. Is the built-in index somehow optimised for enforcing uniqueness, not for selection?
3. Why things look much faster when there is no constraint?

   ```
   create table transaction_backup as select * from transaction; 
   analyze select * from transaction_backup where id='8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b';

   alter table transaction_backup add constraint pk_transaction_backup primary key (id);
   explain analyze select * from transaction_backup where id='8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b';

   alter table transaction_backup drop constraint pk_transaction_backup;
   create index i_transaction_backup__id on transaction_backup(id);
   explain analyze select * from transaction_backup where id='8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b';

   drop index i_transaction_backup__id;
   create unique index i_transaction_backup__id on transaction_backup(id);
   explain analyze select * from transaction_backup where id='8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b';

   alter table transaction_backup add constraint pk_transaction_backup primary key (id);
   explain analyze select * from transaction_backup where id='8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b';
   ```

No index

```
 "Seq Scan on transaction_backup  (cost=0.00..10169.70 rows=1 width=911) (actual time=30.323..68.530 rows=1 loops=1)"
 "  Filter: (id = '8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b'::uuid)"
 "  Rows Removed by Filter: 224135"
 **"Planning time: 1.213 ms"
 "Execution time: 68.591 ms"**
```

PK index

```
"Index Scan using pk_transaction_backup on transaction_backup  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=911) (actual time=0.127..0.129 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (id = '8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b'::uuid)"
**"Planning time: 1.876 ms"
"Execution time: 0.188 ms"**
```

Manual non-unique index only

```
"Index Scan using i_transaction_backup__id on transaction_backup  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=911) (actual time=0.026..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (id = '8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b'::uuid)"
**"Planning time: 0.214 ms"
"Execution time: 0.096 ms"**
```

Manual Unique Index only

```
"Index Scan using i_transaction_backup__id on transaction_backup  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=911) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (id = '8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b'::uuid)"
**"Planning time: 0.340 ms"
"Execution time: 0.054 ms"**
```

PK index + Manual Unique Index

```
"Index Scan using i_transaction_backup__id on transaction_backup  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=911) (actual time=0.121..0.123 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (id = '8946f500-155c-30a1-a7d0-fb56cdfd114b'::uuid)"
**"Planning time: 2.001 ms"
"Execution time: 0.187 ms"**
```

Comment: The cost estimates are identical. The measured execution times are too tiny to be compared in a meaningful way. How often did you run this benchmark? Did you make sure there are no "cache/cold start" distortions?

Comment: For the same columns and same data set, there is no difference between a B-Tree index that was created manually vs automatically and if there is a uniqueness constraint or not.

Comment: The use case for not using the automatically created index is if you already have a *structurally different* index that you have determined works better for your application. For example if you already have an index (id, tx_date, type), that one can also be used to enforce a primary key, so you may not want the extra index on just id.

Comment: There is a difference in microseconds, yes, but I wouldn't call that a difference in performance. Anything that your machine does, can be the root cause for this difference.

Answer (score 3):

You could be seeing the normal affects of jitter in the system.

I'd advise that you take a reasonable sized set of data, and then run a few (hundred/ten) thousand tests to see if there is any significant difference.

Well done for testing, but I think you need a more statistically significant set of data.

(btw see the jitter chart on here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-aurora-update-postgresql-compatibility/ for interesting info).